# How can i change icons from SVG to IMG?

Tags: php, html, image, svg

Can someone help me to change ICONS from SVG to an PNG image or link ?

I have this code here :

```html
<?php if ($wo['config']['second_post_button'] == 'reaction') { ?>
 <!-- reaction -->
 <?php if ( isset($wo['story']['viewmode']) && $wo['story']['viewmode'] == 'lightbox') { ?>
    <div class="wo-reaction wo-reaction-lightbox stat-item unselectable" data-id="<?php echo $wo['story']['id']; ?>">
  <span class="like-btn like-btn-lightbox unselectable" data-id="<?php echo $wo['story']['id']; ?>" >
   <?php
    if ($wo['loggedin'] && Wo_IsReacted($wo['story']['id'], $wo['user']['user_id']) === true) {    
     echo Wo_GetReactedTextIcon($wo['story']['id'], $wo['user']['user_id']);
    } else {   
     echo '<span class="status-reaction-'.$wo['story']['id'].' unselectable"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-thumbs-up"><path d="M14 9V5a3 3 0 0 0-3-3l-4 9v11h11.28a2 2 0 0 0 2-1.7l1.38-9a2 2 0 0 0-2-2.3zM7 22H4a2 2 0 0 1-2-2v-7a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h3"></path></svg> <span class="t_likes'.$wo['story']['id'].'"></span> ' . $wo['lang']['like'] . '</span>';   
    }    
   ?>
  </span>
  <ul class="reactions-box reactions-lightbox-container-<?php echo $wo['story']['id']; ?> unselectable" data-id="<?php echo $wo['story']['id']; ?>" style="<?php if ($wo['language_type'] == 'rtl') {?> left: auto; <?php }else{ ?> right: auto; <?php }?>">

   <?php if (!empty($wo['reactions_types'])) {
       foreach ($wo['reactions_types'] as $key => $value) {
        if ($value['status'] == 1) {
         
        ?>
    <li class="reaction reaction-<?php echo $value['id'];?>" data-reaction="<?php echo $value['name'];?>" data-reaction-id="<?php echo $value['id'];?>" data-reaction-lang="<?php echo $value['name'];?>" data-post-id="<?php echo $wo['story']['id']; ?>" onclick="Wo_RegisterReaction(this,'<?php echo($value['wowonder_small_icon']) ?>',<?php echo($value['is_html']) ?>);">
     <?php if (preg_match("/<[^<]+>/",$value['wowonder_icon'],$m)) {
         echo($value['wowonder_icon']);
       }
       else{ ?>
          <img src="<?php echo($value['wowonder_icon']) ?>">
        <?php } ?>
    </li>
   <?php } } } ?>



   <!-- <li class="reaction reaction-like" data-reaction="Like" data-reaction-lang="<?php echo $wo['lang']['like'];?>" data-post-id="<?php echo $wo['story']['id']; ?>" onclick="Wo_RegisterReaction(this);">
    <div class="emoji emoji--like">
     <div class="emoji__hand"><div class="emoji__thumb"></div></div>
    </div>
   </li>
   <li class="reaction reaction-love" data-reaction="Love" data-reaction-lang="<?php echo $wo['lang']['love'];?>" data-post-id="<?php echo $wo['story']['id']; ?>" onclick="Wo_RegisterReaction(this);">
    <div class="emoji emoji--love">
     <div class="emoji__heart"></div>
    </div>
   </li>
   <li class="reaction reaction-haha" data-reaction="HaHa" data-reaction-lang="<?php echo $wo['lang']['haha'];?>" data-post-id="<?php echo $wo['story']['id']; ?>" onclick="Wo_RegisterReaction(this);">
    <div class="emoji emoji--haha">
     <div class="emoji__face">
      <div class="emoji__eyes"></div>
      <div class="emoji__mouth">
       <div class="emoji__tongue"></div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </li>
   <li class="reaction reaction-wow" data-reaction="Wow" data-reaction-lang="<?php echo $wo['lang']['wow'];?>" data-post-id="<?php echo $wo['story']['id']; ?>" onclick="Wo_RegisterReaction(this);">
    <div class="emoji emoji--wow">
     <div class="emoji__face">
      <div class="emoji__eyebrows"></div>
      <div class="emoji__eyes"></div>
      <div class="emoji__mouth"></div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </li>
   <li class="reaction reaction-sad" data-reaction="Sad" data-reaction-lang="<?php echo $wo['lang']['sad'];?>" data-post-id="<?php echo $wo['story']['id']; ?>" onclick="Wo_RegisterReaction(this);">
    <div class="emoji emoji--sad">
     <div class="emoji__face">
      <div class="emoji__eyebrows"></div>
      <div class="emoji__eyes"></div>
      <div class="emoji__mouth"></div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </li>
   <li class="reaction reaction-angry" data-reaction="Angry" data-reaction-lang="<?php echo $wo['lang']['angry'];?>" data-post-id="<?php echo $wo['story']['id']; ?>" onclick="Wo_RegisterReaction(this);">
    <div class="emoji emoji--angry">
     <div class="emoji__face">
      <div class="emoji__eyebrows"></div>
      <div class="emoji__eyes"></div>
      <div class="emoji__mouth"></div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </li> -->
  </ul>
 </div>
 
 <?php } else { ?>

 <div class="wo-reaction wo-reaction-post stat-item unselectable" data-id="<?php echo $wo['story']['id']; ?>">
  <span class="like-btn like-btn-post unselectable"  data-id="<?php echo $wo['story']['id']; ?>" id="react_<?php echo $wo['story']['id']; ?>" <?php if ($wo['loggedin'] && Wo_IsReacted($wo['story']['id'], $wo['user']['user_id'])) { ?> data_react="1" <?php }else{ ?> data_react="0"<?php } ?> data-reaction-id="<?php echo $wo['reactions_types'][1]['id'];?>"  data-reaction="Like" data-reaction-lang="<?php echo $wo['lang']['like'];?>" data-post-id="<?php echo $wo['story']['id']; ?>" onclick="Wo_RegisterReactionLike(this,'<?php echo($wo['reactions_types'][1]['wowonder_small_icon']) ?>',<?php echo($wo['reactions_types'][1]['is_html']) ?>);">
   <?php
    if ($wo['loggedin'] && Wo_IsReacted($wo['story']['id'], $wo['user']['user_id']) === true) {    
     echo Wo_GetReactedTextIcon($wo['story']['id'], $wo['user']['user_id']);
    } else {   
     echo '<span class="status-reaction-'.$wo['story']['id'].' unselectable"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-thumbs-up"><path d="M14 9V5a3 3 0 0 0-3-3l-4 9v11h11.28a2 2 0 0 0 2-1.7l1.38-9a2 2 0 0 0-2-2.3zM7 22H4a2 2 0 0 1-2-2v-7a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h3"></path></svg> <span class="t_likes'.$wo['story']['id'].'"></span> ' . $wo['lang']['like'] . '</span>';   
    }    
   ?>
  </span>
  <ul class="reactions-box reactions-box-container-<?php echo $wo['story']['id']; ?>" data-id="<?php echo $wo['story']['id']; ?>" style="<?php if ($wo['language_type'] == 'rtl') {?> left: auto; <?php }else{ ?> right: auto; <?php }?>">
   <?php if (!empty($wo['reactions_types'])) {
       foreach ($wo['reactions_types'] as $key => $value) {
        if ($value['status'] == 1) {
         
        ?>
    <li class="reaction reaction-<?php echo $value['id'];?>" data-reaction="<?php echo $value['name'];?>" data-reaction-id="<?php echo $value['id'];?>" data-reaction-lang="<?php echo $value['name'];?>" data-post-id="<?php echo $wo['story']['id']; ?>" onclick="Wo_RegisterReaction(this,'<?php echo($value['wowonder_small_icon']) ?>',<?php echo($value['is_html']) ?>);">
     <?php if (preg_match("/<[^<]+>/",$value['wowonder_icon'],$m)) {
         echo($value['wowonder_icon']);
       }
       else{ ?>
          <img src="<?php echo($value['wowonder_icon']) ?>">
        <?php } ?>
    </li>
   <?php } } } ?>



   <!-- <li class="reaction reaction-like animated_2" data-reaction="Like" data-reaction-lang="<?php echo $wo['lang']['like'];?>" data-post-id="<?php echo $wo['story']['id']; ?>" onclick="Wo_RegisterReaction(this);">
    <div class="emoji emoji--like">
     <div class="emoji__hand"><div class="emoji__thumb"></div></div>
    </div>
   </li>
   <li class="reaction reaction-love animated_4" data-reaction="Love" data-reaction-lang="<?php echo $wo['lang']['love'];?>" data-post-id="<?php echo $wo['story']['id']; ?>" onclick="Wo_RegisterReaction(this);">
    <div class="emoji emoji--love">
     <div class="emoji__heart"></div>
    </div>
   </li>
   <li class="reaction reaction-haha animated_6" data-reaction="HaHa" data-reaction-lang="<?php echo $wo['lang']['haha'];?>" data-post-id="<?php echo $wo['story']['id']; ?>" onclick="Wo_RegisterReaction(this);">
    <div class="emoji emoji--haha">
     <div class="emoji__face">
      <div class="emoji__eyes"></div>
      <div class="emoji__mouth">
       <div class="emoji__tongue"></div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </li>
   <li class="reaction reaction-wow animated_8" data-reaction="Wow" data-reaction-lang="<?php echo $wo['lang']['wow'];?>" data-post-id="<?php echo $wo['story']['id']; ?>" onclick="Wo_RegisterReaction(this);">
    <div class="emoji emoji--wow">
     <div class="emoji__face">
      <div class="emoji__eyebrows"></div>
      <div class="emoji__eyes"></div>
      <div class="emoji__mouth"></div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </li>
   <li class="reaction reaction-sad animated_10" data-reaction="Sad" data-reaction-lang="<?php echo $wo['lang']['sad'];?>" data-post-id="<?php echo $wo['story']['id']; ?>" onclick="Wo_RegisterReaction(this);">
    <div class="emoji emoji--sad">
     <div class="emoji__face">
      <div class="emoji__eyebrows"></div>
      <div class="emoji__eyes"></div>
      <div class="emoji__mouth"></div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </li>
   <li class="reaction reaction-angry animated_12" data-reaction="Angry" data-reaction-lang="<?php echo $wo['lang']['angry'];?>" data-post-id="<?php echo $wo['story']['id']; ?>" onclick="Wo_RegisterReaction(this);">
    <div class="emoji emoji--angry">
     <div class="emoji__face">
      <div class="emoji__eyebrows"></div>
      <div class="emoji__eyes"></div>
      <div class="emoji__mouth"></div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </li> -->
  </ul>
 </div>
 <?php } ?>

<?php }else{ ?>

  <!-- Normal Like -->
  <span onclick="Wo_RegisterLike(<?php echo $wo['story']['id']; ?>);" id="like-button" class="btn btn-default stat-item" title="<?php echo $wo['lang']['like'];?>">
  <?php
  $second_btn_wonder = ($wo['config']['second_post_button'] == 'dislike') ? $wo['lang']['dislike'] : $wo['lang']['wonder'];
  $second_btn_wondered = ($wo['config']['second_post_button'] == 'dislike') ? $wo['lang']['disliked'] : $wo['lang']['wondered'];
  if ($wo['story']['is_liked'] === true) {    
    echo '<span class="active-like"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-thumbs-up"><path d="M14 9V5a3 3 0 0 0-3-3l-4 9v11h11.28a2 2 0 0 0 2-1.7l1.38-9a2 2 0 0 0-2-2.3zM7 22H4a2 2 0 0 1-2-2v-7a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h3"></path></svg> ' . $wo['lang']['liked'] . '</span>';   
  } else {   
    echo '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-thumbs-up"><path d="M14 9V5a3 3 0 0 0-3-3l-4 9v11h11.28a2 2 0 0 0 2-1.7l1.38-9a2 2 0 0 0-2-2.3zM7 22H4a2 2 0 0 1-2-2v-7a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h3"></path></svg> ' . $wo['lang']['like'];   
  }    
  ?>
  </span>
  <?php if ($wo['config']['second_post_button'] != 'disabled') { ?>
  <span onclick="Wo_RegisterWonder(<?php echo $wo['story']['id']; ?>);" id="wonder-button" class="btn btn-default stat-item" title="<?php echo $wo['second_post_button_text'];?>">
  <?php 
  if ($wo['story']['is_wondered'] === true) {  
    echo '<span class="active-wonder">' . $wo['second_post_button_icon'] . '<span class="like-btn-mobile">' . $second_btn_wondered . '</span></span>'; 
  } else {    
    echo '' . $wo['second_post_button_icon'] . ' <span class="like-btn-mobile">' . $second_btn_wonder . '</span>';
  }
  ?>          
  </span>
  <?php } ?>

<?php } ?>
```

This is a button type of : Like Button ... And near the text is a icon..I want to change that icons but i cant,,Because i dont find the SVG files for icons...
Its like a Like Button...Appear a small icon after is the text : Like ..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to convert a few icons by hand, the easiest way would be to take the svg code (everything between `<svg` and `</svg>` copy that into a text editor, save the file as `.svg` and convert it using an online svg-to-png converter.

In your case the svg which appears four times in your code is:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-thumbs-up"><path d="M14 9V5a3 3 0 0 0-3-3l-4 9v11h11.28a2 2 0 0 0 2-1.7l1.38-9a2 2 0 0 0-2-2.3zM7 22H4a2 2 0 0 1-2-2v-7a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h3"></path></svg>
```

Comment: i dont need that icon..i need to change the icon and i dont know how.

Comment: I want to change with other icon

Comment: @OnicaRazvan Your question was _very_ difficult to understand. In that case, you can just remove the svgs as stated above and replace them with images via `<img src="path/to/image.png">`